# Half of the Item in list view is not invoking OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with custom Adapter,

```
public class ClueArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

---
----

@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
---
---
return rowView;
}
```

rowlayout

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/clue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

     <com.mydomain.MyView 
        android:id="@+id/myView"    // MyView is custom view and overrides onTouchEvent
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

### I have a onItemLongClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
 ---
view.setSelected(true);
}
```

This listener is getting invoked when there is a long click on TextView but not responding to long click on myView.

Do i need to set some xml attributes of myView in rowlayout so that a row is selected in responce to a long click on myView too ?

### on touch of myView

```
 @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

            final int action = ev.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final float y = ev.getY();
                    markedCell = getCellAt(x,y);
                    break;       
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Post the code for the onTouchEvent of MyView. I'm guessing that you're consuming the long press event there .

Comment: dymmeh, please see the onTouchEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return false from your onTouchEvent. 
Returning true means that you handled the event and that it shouldn't be passed to the next handler (in this case, your long touch event).

Answer (score 0):

you can set on click listener in your getView method.

```
       rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener)
          {
            public void onclick()
             { //your code
             }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class ClueArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
---
----

@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
  rowView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
         ---
  rowView.setSelected(true);
}

 ---
 ---
return rowView;
```

}

Comment: Thanks I tried this, but was getting error that setOnItemLongClickListener can not be set on this kind of view. So I tried it with setOnItemLongClickListener. Behavior is same.

Comment: RowView has two views in it a TextView and a custom view. The Listener is getting invoked when long click is on area occupied by the TextView.   The custom view 'MyView' has onTouchEven(MotionEven), when this view is touched its onTouchEvent method is invoked. Any touch event is being passed to 'MyView' and its not being passed to listeners on 'RowView' and on ListView